# How to get Count of elements matching a certain attribute value using IDynamoDBContext

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I use IDynamoDBContext in my .net app to do multiple read write operations on dynamodb, Is there any better way get count of all elements matching spefic attribute value other scanning the db for all elemnets and calculating the count

I tried using ScanAsync, just wondering if there’s a better way

Answer (score 0):

Yes, depending on what it is you want to count there is a number of ways to achieve it.

1. Index the attribute. Now instead of doing a Scan you can do a Query and pass the `select:Count` parameter to return the count of items matching that key.
2. You can use DynamoDB streams and Lambda and keep incrementing/decrementing the count in near real time in a counter item in the same table or even a second table. Now you can do a more efficient GetItem to obtain the count.